# Makefile: Why command sequece is executed before call it?

Tags: makefile

Below makefile, ${PATH}/CMD0.log is generated by CMD0.
check_file is command sequence to check warnings from CMD0.log. First it will check if CMD0.log exists.
When run `make clean; make`, it shows CMD0.log doesn't exist.
Since the log is generated by CMD0, not sure why check_file is executed before CMD0.

```
...
define check_file =
    if test -f ${PATH}/CMD0.log; then
        $(eval WARNING = $(shell grep "WARNING.*" ${PATH}/file.log))
    fi
endef 
...
${OUTPUTS0}: ${INPUTS0}
   @echo ""
   @echo "[INFO] STEP0";
   @date '+%Y_%m%d_%H%M'
   ... CMD0 -log CMD0.log ...
   @$(check_file)
```

Screen print

```
-> make clean ; make
grep: ./log/CMD0.log: No such file or directory

[INFO] STEP0
2021_0303_0025
```

`make -d | tee make.log` screen print

```
     Finished prerequisites of target file `target'.
    Must remake target `target'.
grep: ./log/CMD0.log: No such file or directory
Invoking recipe from makefile:137 to update target `target'.
Putting child 0x26490c0 (target) PID 18792 on the chain.
Live child 0x26490c0 (target) PID 18792 

Reaping winning child 0x26490c0 PID 18792 
Live child 0x26490c0 (target) PID 18793 
[INFO] STEP0
Reaping winning child 0x26490c0 PID 18793 
Live child 0x26490c0 (target) PID 18810 
2021_0303_0957
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you, makefiles have to be rerunable. you generally `make` and then `make install` for simple deployments, and what happens if somthing went wrong, or you are updating an existing install?

Comment: Try adding the `-d` parm to make and see if make is doing what you expect it to.  And try running just `make -d clean` first, see if that is behaving, then try `make -d` and review.

Comment: @FrankThomas: it's for FPGA bit generation, since I run `make clean`, it's a clean build, not updating existing run.

Comment: @MarkStewart, tried `-d`, still can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I expect `CMD0 -log CMD0.log` to work with `./CMD0.log`. Then `./log/CMD0.log` is needed and not found. Make sure paths and working directories are what you think they are.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, after remove `CMD0 -log CMD0.log`, it still prints `No such file or directory` message.

Comment: I thought `CMD0 -log CMD0.log` is supposed to create the log. Removing the command will all the more not make it appear where you want it. My point is *maybe* you're looking in the wrong place (`./log/CMD0.log`) when you `grep`.